# Probability of n k-sided dice showing exactly m different faces

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

I found the following closed form solution for the abovementioned problem:

$${1\over k^n}\cdot{k!\over (k-m)!}\cdot{\{{n\over m}\}}$$ with ${\{{n\over m}\}}$ being the Stirling Number of the second kind.

Although it seems to have some intuition and seems to work for a sample problem for which I have the solution this closed form is not from a trusted source. Unfortunately I can't find any other source.

**My question**: Could anyone acknowledge this closed form solution and/or give me a hint where to find a citable source.

Comment: There are $k^n$ possible dice configurations, presumably all equally likely.

$\frac{k!}{(k-m)!}$ is the number of distinct combinations of $m$ (out of $k$ total) faces.

The Stirling number of the second kind is the number of ways to separate n elements into m sets. 

Comment: In other words, this is not far from the definition of the Stirling number of the second kind. See equation 11 in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html. Set x=k and divide both sides by k^n. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applied probability by Kenneth Lange deals with this problem on page 74. It is on Google books, here is the [URL](http://books.google.com/books?id=otp4TDnz6FwC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=Stirling+Number+of+the+second+kind+dice&source=bl&ots=YHHbtcknAO&sig=sGd1_d1UXtlNkWGYINVZH6Tadu0&hl=en&ei=boiBS-CpDImKsgOq6en5Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=Stirling%2520Number%2520of%2520the%2520second%2520kind%2520dice&f=false).